# git cvsimport: what does 'remote' refer to?

Tags: git, git-svn, cvs, git-cvs

i copied files from old cvs repo locally. when i do

```
git cvsimport -C . -d path-to-cvs-folder some-module
```

it creates a git repo with branches so then i can push the whole repo into github:

```
git push --mirror git@github.com:xxx.git
```

but the `cvsimport` creates `master` branch and also `origin` branch pointing to the same commit as `master`. there are no remotes created: `git remote -v` returns nothing

the question is: what is the purpose of the `origin` branch? in the manual there is `-r` switch to let me name that branch. but what for? there is no remote repo at the of migration - just locally copied cvs files. what's the idea behind it?

Comment: Did you check `git remote -v`? What does it say?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it returns nothing. i updated the question

Comment: There is some documentation regarding those origins - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsimport - see if it explains it. Note that if you don't create a remote named origin, there's nothing stopping you from creating a branch named `origin/x`, it's just a branch name like any other, it's only when you add a remote named `origin` it takes on the meaning of "the branch `x` on the remote `origin`", and this meaning is loose at best.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `git cvsimport` but it is clear from the documentation that it can be used incrementally, i.e., you can import some CVS repository, then later import any *changes* since the previous import.  The `-r` switch and the names created from it are clearly intended for cvsimport's own internal use: when you do an incremental import, cvsimport uses something(s) stored in the `origin` branch(es) (or whatever name you choose here) to allow it to import only *new* changesets deduced by [`cvsps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cvsps).

As [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsimport) says:

> If you are performing a one-shot import of a CVS repository consider using cvs2git or cvs-fast-export.

These do not need special branches containing whatever it is that `cvsimport` stores there.  They won't create an `origin` name that kind of gets in the way when you want to create a *remote* named `origin`.

(Incidentally, *Git* is just fine with having both a *branch* named `origin`, and a *remote* named `origin`.  Remote-tracking names live in the `refs/remotes/` namespace while branch names live in the `refs/heads/` namespace, so these will never collide; and the remote names themselves live only in the configuration file.  It's only the *shortened* names, like `origin/master`, that Git uses for human convenience and comprehension that collide here.  But this is very confusing to humans, who want to use the shortened names.)